# Values not getting added in Add Datarow activity in UI path

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio

I am trying to add certain values in the Add datarow activity in the UI path from the ArrayRow input. But when i pass the values example {"1","2","3"}, it shows error ';' expected. And when I run the application I get a runtime error. attaching screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your full workflow

Comment: Can you post the screenshots in a higher resolution? It is difficult to read what you are trying to attempt.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to **Properties** of **Add Data Row** activity:

1. **ArrayRow Input** Property needs to be an Object, so you need to pass the values via a variable.
2. **DataTable Input** needs to contain a Table that has been initialized already, if the Table does not exist UiPath will generate an error

Please check the solution below as per your values:

[image]

**Variables** are the following:

[image]

Initialize your **DataTable variable** if you have not done it before in your Workflow:

[image]

And then populate your **Add Data Row activity** as follow:

[image]

If you run this **Workflow** in **Output pane** you will see the value of first row in DataTable that will be **1,2,3**.

Hope these information will be useful.